# Using self in database field updates in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand why I get a `nil` error below.  But when I add `self` I don't get the error and everything gets assigned corrected.  Can you explain to me why if I don't use `self` this does not work?

models/user.rb

```
def update_user_email!(new_email)
  email = new_email # When I use self.name = new_email this works
end
```

controllers/users_controller

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  @user.update_user_email!(email)
  @user.save
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are in a method inside a model, if you use just the attribute name it will treat it like a variable with the scope limited to this method.  Using self.attribute will actually access the underlying field in the model and let you assign values.

As a basic rule, any time you are actually assigning values in a model, you should always use

```
self.attribute = value
```

On a side point, I am not sure if your code was for example only, but it doesn't like look a method you would need.

In the controller you could just do

```
@user.email = email
```